# Automatically formatting HTML within PHP with VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I tried Intelephense and dozens of other extensions and settings but NONE of them achieved what I'm after. What I prioritize is automatic tag close and automatic indent... most of others VSC functionalities for HTML would be great too, like css classes or files paths suggestions, but what I really need is this 'basic' automatic format...

I'm sorry for this question, I know it's been done and answered before, it's just that I can't get my VSC to correctly work with HTML when mixed with PHP, and I've been trying for months now... Read everything I've found on Google, searched about it here and on Reddit, but wasn't able to reproduce any of the solutions, or better saying, none of them worked for me.

Could anyone give me some guidance?

Answer (score 1):

Luckily I felt the same way as you so I just decided to go ahead and hammer out a solution to this very annoying problem with a VScode extension that doesn't register itself as a "formatting" extension I format the HTML onBeforeSave so you can still register a PHP formatting extension so between the two it gets the whole file. I use js-beautify so you can just use all the native HTML formatting settings in VSCode already.

[Format HTML in PHP](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rifi2k.format-html-in-php) on the VSCode Extension Marketplace.

Comment: Didn't know about that extension, looks great, currently I just change the language in VSCode to HTML at the bottom bar if I need to work just on the HTML lol

Comment: How does this work with closing quotes automatically?